# Can i make unit testing using cxxtest with visual studio 2010 professional?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, cxxtest

Can i make unit testing using cxxtest with visual studio 2010 professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! I've done that.

Just create a vcproj template where the UnitTest.h file has a custom build step which run the test generation code (cxxtestgen.py) which will generate UnitTest.cpp.
Now you can create new projects from that template and it will work like a charm.